# Toxic former PI trying to block me from publication

Tags: publications, authorship

I was a Master's student and worked as an RA for a professor. I signed a contract and submitted. The professor would assign me work on a weekly basis. By the end of my RAship, I asked the professor to get paid. The professor told me that the RAship was never formally established due to administrative reasons, and he thought "I never worked for him as an RA", and I was merely working on my own project in his lab. At the same time, he suggested that he would write me a strong LOR. At this time, I was working on one paper with him, and the paper is based on the work from my RAship. He even told me to note the funding grants in my paper. I finished editing the paper and added more information based on the things he told me. He promised me that he would edit the paper in several emails in the span of several months and promised me to publish the paper on a good journal, but he never edited it. At this time, I thought he was just using the publication and LOR to blackmail me so I wouldn't ask him for the salary. So I filed a complaint letter to the head of the department. Shortly after, the head of the department told me that the department will compensate me for the salary, despite the fact that it was funded by his grant. Right after I filed the complaint and had a meeting with the head of the department, the professor started to retaliate against me. He removed me from the lab and any information I have on his website. Removed all the publized work I had and banned me from accessing the documents he and I wrote when I was an RA. I then asked him about the publication. He told me that he never planned to work on the paper and the paper has nothing to do with him, which is a lie. I then asked if I could publish the paper alone without him. He told me that the data I used doesn't belong to me and because I have already graduated, I don't have the authorization to use the data. I told the retalitary information to the head of the department. The head said that he can't do anything about it because I can't force the professor to work on the paper.

I don't know what to do. I feel like I am dealing with a gang, and the whole thing has made me depressed for a long time.

Comment: which country? it looks like a question for Law_SE rather than Academia ...

Comment: United States of America

Comment: If you signed a contract that makes you employed as far as I know, I don't think employers are allowed to make administrative errors without telling an employee to avoid paying. Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a much better fit for sites giving information on legal proceeding or workplace issues, like Law or Workplace Stack Exchange

Comment: I voted "needs more details" in the close vote: I think this would be answerable if we had a better idea whether the Prof had contributed enough to the paper to merit co-authorship, and therefore to have a veto on publication.

Comment: @DanielHatton - given the professor was assigning the work weekly, that seems a pretty clear contribution.

Comment: If the professor does not yet have tenure, not paying your RA and making the department pay instead is probably a good way to throw a monkey wrench in his tenure case (especially if you are not the only one he's behaved done things like this to).

Comment: Wait you signed an RA contract with the professor? That is odd. Are you sure it wasn’t some sort of independent study agreement? At my university, only HR can do this sort of contract, not the professor. You would be filling out W2, submitting copy of ID etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer and this is no legal counselling.

Big part of the question deals with legal matters, i.e. the agreement you signed.

Another big part hinges on the petty behavior of your former boss ... all my support regarding this, unfortunately it is nothing unheard of, in academia or outside of it. Academia is much worse because of the byzantine referral system.

The third part is common and fair in academia: you may have access to some data as long as you are part of a research group and as long as the research group agree in you accessing them.
Here there is probably a power-sharing/responsibility management issue, i.e. the professor does what they want.
The professor ousted you, so you are no longer part and you have no more access to the data/infrastructure. The head of department is probably too busy to deal with your case (it is no excuse, just the cause of his behavior).

In short and sadly: nothing for you there. The bridges are burned, it is up to you to decide if you want to stir the mess (supported by legal counselling) or let it go. We do not know the details of the agreement, you may legally force your way to access the data you worked on during your RA time, but this is just my speculation, I am not a lawyer and this is no legal counselling.